# Pressing "OK" in a dialog from a batch file

Tags: batch-file, modal-dialog

Another tech and I have been writing a batch file to install about 13 programs with little user time at the computer. We have 12 programs installing with no issues, but the last program wants to be a pain.

If we put /silence in the string the program does not install, if we remove /silence it will install but afterwards a popup screen comes up telling that the programs has been installed and we have to press the ok for the batch file to continue.

Is there any way of having the batch file select ok for us?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the batch can just close the popup to proceed:

```
wmic process where name="Pop_Up_Name.exe" call terminate
```

Comment: Will try that monday  11/3 and see if it will till work right and will get back to you. thanks for the suggestion.